# sending the data from form to db in django

Tags: python, django

I have a form in which I can input text through text boxes.
How do I make these data go into the db on clicking submit.

this is the code of the form in the template.

```
<form method="post" action="app/save_page">
<p>
Title:<input type="text" name="title"/>
</p>
<p>
Name:<input type="text" name="name"/>
</p>
<p>
Phone:<input type="text" name="phone"/>
</p>
<p>
Email:<input type="text" name="email"/>
</p>
<p>
<textarea name="description" rows=20 cols=60>
</textarea><br>
</p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

I have a function in the views.py for saving the data in the page. But I dont know how to impliment it properly:

```
def save_page(request):
   title = request.POST["title"]
   name = request.POST["name"]
   phone = request.POST["phone"]
   email = request.POST["email"]
   description = request.POST["description"]
```

Now how do I send these into the db?

And what do I put in views.py so that those data goes into the db? 
so how do I open a database connection and put those into the db and save it?

should I do something like :

```
connection=sqlite3.connect('app.db')
cursor= connection.cursor()
.....
.....
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Django will do this for you, but you need to create a form. You should read about [forms in Django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/forms/#topics-forms-index) and [creating forms from models](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/).

It's not necessary to accomplish this particular task, but you should also read about [Django ORM](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/topics/db/queries/#topics-db-queries).

Try reading [the official documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/) or one of the Django books (I learned Django from "Practical Django projects" and "The Django Book").

Answer (score 2):

This question is asking for a brief description of the whole Djando DB model.

The short answer is you don't connect to the DB from the view, you have to use Django DB API. You have to define the model class in your models.py and then use class methods to update the data. Django will take care of passing/storing that in the DB.

Anticipating your question 'how?' I unfortunately will have to point you to the official [DJango documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/).

Update: Another [good resource about Django](http://www.djangobook.com/) with comments, notes and examples.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Exactly.."how" is my question. The django does seems to be so un friendly for a beginner. Looks like its just a reference for the pros..They don't explain with one single example but keep jumping here & there. Anyways I'll have to manage with that.

Comment: I see what you mean. It does require some level of digging around and trying out things before it all starts to make sense. I have update my answer with another link, which may be useful when starting with Django. Once you get used to it, it's not so unfriendly! :)

Comment: ok. I will read through  The django book ... would have been really helpful if they had something for django like railscast for rails :)

Answer (score 0):

You can save send data into the django databse easily by working with django forms. Django forms make saving db data easily by linking your forms to your models through the ModelForm. Read the documention on django forms, modelforms, and the ORM.
The following links may help you. I use django 1.9 at the moment

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform